# Duplicate symbol _calculate_string error message iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This is the error code i get when i attempt to build for testing, how do i find the cause for this error. I had duplicted 2 files in xcode and made subtle changes to copy in order to make a second screen.

```
ld: duplicate symbol _calculate_string in /Users/Lucky3kj/Library/Developer/Xcode   /DerivedData/MiniCalculator-ebxkovztnlrphaahncircdyuwjgc/Build/Intermediates/MiniCalculator.build/Debug-iphoneos/PipeFitter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/RollingOffsetLeftViewController.o and /Users/Lucky3kj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MiniCalculator-ebxkovztnlrphaahncircdyuwjgc/Build/Intermediates/MiniCalculator.build/Debug-iphoneos/PipeFitter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/RollingOffsetAnyAngleViewController.o for architecture armv7
   Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please work on your code formatting next time, thank you.

Comment: Did you remember to change the name of the class in both the `.h` and `.m`?

Comment: @Paul.s _calculate_string seems to me like a function name, not a class name. Which is where my answer comes from. If I am wrong, please tell me so I can correct my answer.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm not sure if your answer is correct (is seems plausible to me, but I'm not that experienced with C) but yes I can confirm my suggestion would result in `duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_A`, which is not the same as the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is an error that stems from C.

If, in one .c file I have the following:

```
void myFunction(int myArg)
{
    printf("%i", myArg);  
}
```

And in another file I have this function:

```
void myFunction(int myArg)
{
     printf("MyArg is: %i", myArg);
}
```

When the compiler links your project, and you call

```
myFunction(10);
```

The compiler does not know which version of your method to call, so the solution is one of the following:

1) Define the method once, and include only the prototype of the function. Example:

```
// instead of implementing myFunction here, we do this:
void myFunction(int myArg);
// and implement myFunction in another file.

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    myFunction(10);
}
```

2) Define the method twice, but add the static qualifier to it, which tells the linker that this is the only file that can use this function.

```
// FileOne.c

static void myFunction(int myArg)
{
    printf("myArg is: %i", myArg);
}

// FileTwo.c

static void myFunction(int myArg)
{
    printf("%i", myArg);
}
```

Honestly, for simplicity, I would recommend just using the static qualifier, but thats just my preference when It comes to these matters.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally come where you have done a circular reference or making two class files with same name.